# Merge vertices while inseting ver. 2.82

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have issue with inset feature, works fine on regular shapes, but when the faces has odd shapes, there is a lot of faces overlapping.

I have read that there is an option that allows to auto merge vertices while inseting, but i can't find the option. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm trying to envision a scenario where this function would be of use. As I see it, while insetting, you don't want vertices to even collide with existing ones that might exist on the initial plane, let alone merge with them. Would you be willing to go into more detail about what you are actually trying to do? There may be another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the *Straight Skeleton Inset* function.
It's basically a 'smarter' inset tool.

1. Enable it in *Preferences > Addons > Inset Straight Skeleton*
2. Select your faces and go Face > Inset Straight Skeleton
3. Done.

*You can see the vertices are merging, instead of overlapping.*

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :).

Comment: @RobinBetts Glad you find it useful. It's odd such a tool is hidden by default :).

Comment: Could be a standard option of the Inset tool