# Why the mesh is not inset good way?

Tags: modeling

I have this small triangular mesh. Extracted from the main mesh. The scale rotation are set to 1 and 0. yet to the inset not working good way. I want to have a triangular inset which its not making with my mesh. Its created some ngons and extra edges.

[image]

[image]

Any help or suggestion to inset the face. Thanks

Comment: Your polygon is not a traingle, there is very small edge (top corner) which overlaps quite easily, due to its relative shortness to adjacent edges. Either make a true triangle from it or merge overlapped geometry after inseting or use shipped add-on called "Inset Straight Skeleton", which insets without overlapping.

Comment: @SergeL Thanks for the suggestion its really awesome addon. I got the perfect result

Comment: @SergeL Hello :). Inset Straight Skeleton is a useful but not very well known addon. Please, consider making your comment a full answer :).

Answer (score 4):

**Why is it overlapping?**

Your polygon is not a traingle, there is very small edge (top corner) which overlaps quite easily with default inset tool, due to its relative shortness to adjacent edges.

**How to prevent overlapping?**

Either merge overlapped geometry after inseting or use shipped add-on called *Inset Straight Skeleton* (Blender 2.8x) or *Inset Polygon* (Blender 2.7x), which insets without overlapping. Actually, add-on automatically merges overlapped geometry on every appearance, creating extra loops.

[SE: Inset Straight Skeleton enabling and usage info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180167/29200)

Sometimes skeleton inset produces bad geometry (wavy and not even) due to precision issues with merging distance. There is a trick to obtain beter results, it involves scaling:

1. Scale a polygon in edit mode *n* times (used n=10 factor for pic example)
2. Inset with *amount* * *n* (inset should be relatively bigger)
3. Scale *1/n* times (everything goes back to initial size)

"Scale trick" pic example: (it is a long polygon, but in perpective view for better visibility)

[image]