# Blender 2.83: A shipped add-on is not appearing in the Face context menu

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I was recently made aware of the shipped *Straight Skeleton Inset* add-on  by [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191278/35559) and [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180167/35559) on BSE.

I could use this a lot, but in my setup, (2.83 stable), script version 1.1 in `.. /scripts/addons ..`, it's not appearing in any menu.

I can access the operator via <kbd>F3</kbd>, but this doesn't allow me to make a shortcut of Quick Menu entry.

The add-on script includes:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_InsetStraightSkeleton)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_faces.append(menu)
```

Should this work? Any clue what else might be going wrong?

Comment: No issue using Blender 2.83.4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0QZM.png (call you've posted is correct) and I can add it to the quick favs as well.

Comment: @brockmann Thanks, that helps my hunt, must be an external conflict of some kind, I guess.. I'll run Blender otherwise clean, and see if it works on its own

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Comment: @brockmann nope, executes normally from F3, just invisible to menu. Can't get to it right now, will try again p.m.